# Is there any way to correct the scope of variable/object in legacy projects using automated tools

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Is there any way to correct the scope of variable/object in vast legacy projects using automated tools. Can any one please suggest some free license tools so that it can be very useful for me.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I would like to correct the scope of variables across the project.

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but read the guidelines for questions. They are a bit different to SO.